slow disk ejection macbook air M3
On a new Macbook air M3 (macOS 14 Sonoma), when I try to eject my external hard drive (eject button in the Finder), it takes a very long time.
The hard drive is connected through a hub via USB-A 3.0 and the hub is connected to the Macbook via one of the USB-C ports.

Why is the dismount so slow?
How can I make it quicker?


How long is "very long"?

• What is the brand of hub & external disk? Is the hub powered or unpowered? • Are there other devices connected to the same hub? If so, what are they? • How is the external drive formatted? APFS? HFS+? exFAT?

Were you copying or moving files to the drive prior to ejecting it?

The first step in troubleshooting this would be to remove the hub from between the drive and the Mac. If it is even a little faster it's the hub, otherwise you need to look elsewhere.
